# Custom date picker , not able to set value flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have created custom date picker. Date picker is working file but trying to update value on Textfield directly without opening Date picker is not working.

Setting value from date picker is working, And the problem is when Data is being fetched from serve and wants to populate date picker value is not working

```
class QDatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final String title;
  final String? validateMsg;
  final InputDecoration? inputDecoration;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final AutovalidateMode? autoValidateMode;
  final Function(String, DateTime)? onChanged;
  final Function(String)? onSave;
  final Function(String)? validator;
  final bool isTitleAbove;
  final bool isMandatory;
  final bool enabled;
  final DateTime? initialDate;
  final DateTime firstDate;
  final DateTime lastDate;
  final DateFormat formatter;
  final Theme? datePickerTheme;
  final TextStyle? labelStyle;
  final dynamic suffixIcon;
  final dynamic prefixIcon;
  final bool showDefaultSuffixDateIcon;

  final bool hideTitle;
  final String? errorMsg;

  QDatePicker({
    Key? key,
    this.hintText = "hint",
    this.validator,
    this.inputDecoration,
    this.validateMsg,
    this.onChanged,
    this.textStyle,
    this.autoValidateMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
    this.onSave,
    this.isTitleAbove = true,
    this.title = 'Title',
    this.isMandatory = true,
    this.enabled = true,
    this.datePickerTheme,
    this.initialDate,
    this.labelStyle,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.suffixIcon,
    this.hideTitle = false,
    this.errorMsg,
    this.showDefaultSuffixDateIcon = true,
    DateTime? firstDate,
    DateTime? lastDate,
    DateFormat? formatter,
  })  : firstDate = firstDate ?? DateTime(2012),
        lastDate = lastDate ?? DateTime(2030),
        formatter = formatter ?? DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy'),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QDatePicker> createState() => _QDatePickerState();
}

class _QDatePickerState extends State<QDatePicker> {
  bool obscureText = false;
  late TextEditingController controller;
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  late TextStyle labelStyle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TextEditingController();
    if (widget.initialDate != null) {
      String formattedDate = widget.formatter.format(widget.initialDate!);
      debugPrint(
          'initial date ${widget.initialDate} ----> formattedDate ---> $formattedDate');
      selectedDate = widget.initialDate!;
      controller.text = formattedDate;
      if (widget.onChanged != null) {
        widget.onChanged!(controller.text, selectedDate);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.labelStyle != null) {
      labelStyle = widget.labelStyle!;
    } else if (Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle != null) {
      labelStyle = Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle!;
    } else {
      labelStyle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 15);
    }

return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    widget.isTitleAbove && !widget.hideTitle
        ? Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: widget.title,
                  style: labelStyle,
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: widget.isMandatory ? ' *' : '',
                        style: labelStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.red))
                  ]),
            ),
          )
        : const SizedBox(),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        autovalidateMode: widget.autoValidateMode,
        decoration: widget.inputDecoration ??
            textInputDecoration(
                widget.hintText.trim(),
                widget.isMandatory,
                context,
                widget.isTitleAbove,
                widget.title,
                widget.hideTitle),
        style: widget.textStyle ?? bottomTextStyle(context),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
        enabled: widget.enabled,
        readOnly: true,
        onChanged: (value) {},
        onTap: () async {
          if (widget.enabled) {
            //show dialog
            QCommon.hideKeyboard();
            if (Platform.isIOS) {
              await buildCupertinoDatePicker(context);
            } else {
              await buildMaterialDatePicker(widget.firstDate,
                  widget.lastDate, widget.datePickerTheme);
            }
          }
        },
        validator: (val) {
          if (!widget.isMandatory) {
            return null;
          } else if (widget.validator != null) {
            return widget.validator!(val!);
          } else {
            if (val == null || val.isEmpty) {
              return widget.errorMsg ?? 'Select ${widget.title}';
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
        },
        onSaved: (newValue) {
          if (widget.onSave != null && newValue != null) {
            widget.onSave!(newValue);
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

```
  updateDateInUi() {
    String formattedDate = widget.formatter.format(selectedDate);
    setState(() {
      controller.text = formattedDate;
      if (widget.onChanged != null) {
        widget.onChanged!(controller.text, selectedDate);
      }
    });
  }

  /// This builds material date picker in Android
  buildMaterialDatePicker(
      DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate, Theme? datePickerTheme) async {
    var pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: firstDate,
        lastDate: lastDate,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
          return datePickerTheme ?? bindTheming(context, child);
        });

    if (pickedDate != selectedDate && pickedDate != null) {
      selectedDate = pickedDate;
      updateDateInUi();
    }
  }

  /// This builds cupertino date picker in iOS
  Future<DateTime?> buildCupertinoDatePicker(BuildContext context) async {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext builder) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
            child: CupertinoDatePicker(
              mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
              onDateTimeChanged: (picked) {
                if (picked != selectedDate) {
                  selectedDate = picked;
                  updateDateInUi();
                }
              },
              initialDateTime: selectedDate,
              minimumYear: 2000,
              maximumYear: 2025,
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  InputDecoration textInputDecoration(String? hintText, bool isMandatory,
      BuildContext context, bool isTitleAbove, String? title, bool hideTitle) {
    return InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      hintText: hintText,
      label: !isTitleAbove & !hideTitle
          ? RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: title ?? "Title",
                  style: labelStyle,
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: isMandatory ? ' *' : '',
                        style: labelStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.red))
                  ]),
            )
          : null,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 12),
      suffixIcon: widget.suffixIcon ??
          (widget.showDefaultSuffixDateIcon
              ? IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  onPressed: () {
                    QCommon.hideKeyboard();
                  },
                )
              : null),
      prefixIcon: widget.prefixIcon,
      suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30),
      prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30),
    );
  }
}

Widget bindTheming(BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
  return Theme(
    data: QCommon.isDarkMode()
        ? ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
              onPrimary: QDarkThemeColors.primaryColor,
              // selected text color
              onSurface: QDarkThemeColors.secondaryColor,
              //header background
              surface: QDarkThemeColors.primaryColorDark,
              // default text color
              primary: QDarkThemeColors.accentColor,
              // circle color
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: QDarkThemeColors.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: QDarkThemeColors.accentColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 12),
                    foregroundColor: QDarkThemeColors.accentColor,
                    // color of button's letters
                    // backgroundColor: QDarkThemeColors.primaryColorDark, // Background color
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            width: 1,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)))),
          )
        : ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
              // selected text color
              onPrimary: QLightThemeColors.primaryColorDark,
              // default text color
              onSurface: QLightThemeColors.neutralBlackColor,
              surface: QLightThemeColors.primaryColorLight2,
              // circle color
              primary: QLightThemeColors.primaryColorLight2,
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: QLightThemeColors.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: QLightThemeColors.accentColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 12),
                  foregroundColor: QLightThemeColors.accentColor,
                  // color of button's letters
                  //backgroundColor: QLightThemeColors.primaryColorDark,
                  // Background color
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: const BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          width: 1,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50))),
            ),
            datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData(
              //todayBorder: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 0.9),
              todayForegroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                // If the button is pressed, return green, otherwise blue
                /*  if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                  return QLightThemeColors.primaryColorLight2;
                }*/
                return QLightThemeColors.accentColor;
              }),
            )),
    child: child ?? const Text(""),
  );
}

TextStyle bottomTextStyle(BuildContext context) {
  return TextStyle(
      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.color, fontSize: 12);
}
```

Implementation of Datepicker

```
QDatePicker(
                                title: AppStrings.kDOB,
                                hintText: AppStrings.kDOBHint,
                                firstDate: sixtyY,
                                lastDate: eighteenY,
                                formatter: formatter,
                                isMandatory: false,
                                onChanged: (string, dateTime) {
                                  dob = string;
                                  dob = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                                      .format(dateTime)
                                      .toString();
                                },
                              )

  static DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
  final today = DateTime.now();
  late DateTime eighteenY;
  late DateTime sixtyY;
  eighteenY = DateTime(today.year - 18, today.month, today.day);
  sixtyY = DateTime(today.year - 60, today.month, today.day);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update 1

I would update this method to accept a DateTime instead of relying on the `selectedDate` in the StatefulWidget's state:

```
 updateDateInUi(DateTime newDate) { // Do this 
    String formattedDate = widget.formatter.format(newDate); // Update
    setState(() {
      controller.text = formattedDate;
      if (widget.onChanged != null) {
        widget.onChanged!(controller.text, newDate); // update
      }
    });
  }
```

---

## Update 2

Your example does not provide an `initialDate` to the custom date picker so I wouldn't expect it to be prepopulated:

```
QDatePicker(
                                title: AppStrings.kDOB,
                                hintText: AppStrings.kDOBHint,
                                firstDate: sixtyY,
                                lastDate: eighteenY,
                                formatter: formatter,
                                isMandatory: false,
                                onChanged: (string, dateTime) {
                                  dob = string;
                                  dob = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                                      .format(dateTime)
                                      .toString();
                                },
                              )
```

The issue is related to the `onTap` callback of your TextFormField:

```
        onTap: () async {
          if (widget.enabled) {
            //show dialog
            QCommon.hideKeyboard();
            if (Platform.isIOS) {
              await buildCupertinoDatePicker(context);
            } else {
              await buildMaterialDatePicker(widget.firstDate,
                  widget.lastDate, widget.datePickerTheme);
            }
          }
        },
```

One solution would be to move the creation of the date pickers to an IconButton in the TextFormField's suffixIcon.

The other solution would be to actually set `enabled` = false when calling QDatePicker. In your example, it looks like it is always true so tapping the text field will always open the DatePicker.

Comment: Setting value from date picker is working, But the problem is when i'm fetching data  from serve and wants to populate date picker value is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by its not working? Like you don't see the value from the server?

Comment: In your example, you aren't setting initialDate

Comment: intial date is being assigned to `selectedDate`

Comment: need to ` controller.text` reset again when widget is build already. Everthing is being done in `initState` so it won't update after build of datepicker

Comment: Edited my answer. If the issue is that you want to prepopulate the date picker field with some date fetched from the server, you need to provide that to the custom date picker as the `initialDate`.

Comment: `updateDateInUi` is being updated,  that's not the issue, once the ui build, and my new data is available without selecting date from datepicker, i need to fill in Datepicker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256229/discussion-between-code-on-the-rocks-and-farhana-naaz-ansari).